# Is "required" a correct verb in sentence "Bicycle purist required to travel for work"?

Tags: word-usage

Is "required" a correct verb in sentence

> Bicycle purist required to travel for work

For me this sentence sounds like

> We are searching for bicycle purist who can travel for work.

So I expect at least

> Bicycle purist IS required to travel for work

or

> Bicycle purist is asked/forced to travel for work.

Sentence is taken from [Bicycle purist required to travel for work](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/85225/bicycle-purist-required-to-travel-for-work)

Comment: The title (it's *not* a full sentence) could be paraphrased "How to handle a situation where a bicycle purist is required to travel (a great distance) as part of his job responsibilities (and objects to the distance)"

Comment: It's not a complete sentence.

Comment: @TRomano, wow! But is it still correct? "required" expresses "has to/supposed to" and not "[we] need/[bicycle purist] wanted"?

Comment: Please do not use the backtick (`) to highlight sentences or other expressions  on this site.

Comment: @Clare, which method is supposed to be used to highlight sentences here?

Comment: I've edited to use the accepted format. Generally, it's prefixing with >

Comment: No, Ivan, it is not a help-wanted ad. They don't need a bicycle purist. They already have a bicycle purist, whose principles are in conflict with his job duties.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is in a "newspaper title" format that removes words that aren't absolutely necessary to convey the overall meaning.  In this case, it's a reduced form of:

> A bicycle "purist" who works for me is required to do some business travel. (And how do I handle the situation?)

One of the problems with removing all "unnecessary" words is that, without further context, the reader has to guess the most likely meaning.  It could just as easily be:

> (A) bicycle purist (is happy that he is) required to travel (by bicycle) for work.

or

> We need a bicycle purist who wants to travel for work (by bicycle).

These are not likely, but certainly *possible*.

Otherwise the sentence by itself is not complete since, as you point out, it's missing the "to be" verb *is*.